# Finding the end of a contiguous substring of a string without iteration or RegEx

Tags: python, parsing

I'm trying to write an iterative LL(*k*) parser, and I've gotten strings down pretty well, because they have a start and end token, and so you can just `"".join(tokenlist[string_start:string_end])`.

Numbers, however, do not, and only consist of `.0123456789`. They can occur at any given point in a program, have any arbitrary length and are delimited purely by non-numerals.

Some examples, because that definition is pretty vague:

```
56 123.45/!     is 56 and 123.45 followed by two other tokens

565.5345.345 %  is 565.5345, 0.345 and two other tokens (incl. whitespace)
```

The problem I'm trying to solve is how the parser should figure out where a numeric literal ends. (Note that this is a context-free, self-modifying interpretive grammar thus there is no *separate* lexical analysis to be done.)

I could and have solved this with iteration:

```
def _next_notinst(self, atindex, subs = DIGITS):
    """return the next index of a char not in subs"""
    for i, e in enumerate(self.toklist[atindex:]):
        if e not in subs:
            return i - len(self.toklist)
        else:
            break
    return self.idx.v
```

<sup>(I don't think I need to clarify the variables, since it's an example and extremely straightforward.)</sup>

Great! That works, but there are at least two issues:

- It's *O(n)* for a number with digit-length *n*. *Not* ideal.*
- The parser class of which this method is a member is already using a `while True:` to cycle over arbitrary parts of the string, and I would prefer *not* having remotely nested loops when I don't *need* to.
- From the previous bullet: since the parser uses arbitrary *k* lookahead and *skip*ahead, [parsing each individual token is absolutely ***not*** what I want](https://github.com/catb0t/mouse16/blob/master/mouse16.py#L773).

I don't want to use RegEx mostly because I don't know it, and using it for this right now would make my code uncomprehendable to *me*, its creator.

There must be a simple, < *O(n)* solution to this, that simply collects the contiguous numerals in a string given a starting point, up until a non-numeral.

---

*Yes, I'm fully aware *the parser itself* is *O(n)*, but we don't *also* need the number catenator to be > *O(n)*. If you don't believe me, the string catenator is *O(1)* because it simply looks for the next unescaped `"` in the program and then joins all the chars up to that. Can't I do the same thing for numbers?

Comment: Can numbers happen inside string delimiters?

Comment: @Daenyth They *can* happen, but everything between a `"` double quote and another double quote that isn't preceded by a \ backslash is a string. The parser builds a table of ranges of strings as it goes, so it never jumps inside a string literal, and strings have precedence over numerals.

Comment: The method that deals with numbers is only called if the parser finds a numeric literal outside a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>My other answer was actually erroneous due to lack of testing.</sup>

> I decided to suck it up and learn a little bit of RegEx just because it's the only other way to solve this.

[`^([.\d]+[.\d]+|[.\d])`](https://regex101.com/r/kO8nY2/1)  works for what **I** want, and matches these:

```
123.43.453""

.234234!/%
```

but not, for example:

```
"1233
```